# Accessing JBoss JMX data via JSON

Tags: json, jboss, jmx

Is there a way to access the JBoss JMX data via JSON?

I am trying to pull a management console together using data from a number of different servers. I can achieve this using screen scraping, but I would prefer to use a JSON object or XML response if one exists, but I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org), a full featured JSON/HTTP adapter for JMX. 
It supports and has been tested on JBoss as well as on many other platforms. Jolokia
is an agent, which is deployed as a normal Java EE war, so you simply drop it into your
`deploy` directory within you JBoss installation. Also, there a some client libraries available, e.g. [jmx4perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org) which allows for programatic access to the agent.

There is much [more](http://www.jolokia.org/features-nb.html) to discover and it is actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, then you can make small program that make JMX request to JBoss server and transform the response into XML/JSON.

Following is small code snippet. This may help you.

```
String strInitialProp = "javax.management.builder.initial";
System.setProperty(strInitialProp, "mx4j.server.MX4JMBeanServerBuilder");
String urlForJMX = "jnp://localhost:1099";//for jboss

ObjectName objAll = ObjectName.getInstance("*:*");  
JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(urlForJMX);
MBeanServerConnection jmxServerConnection = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxUrl).getMBeanServerConnection();

System.out.println("Total MBeans :: "+jmxServerConnection.getMBeanCount());
Set mBeanSet = jmxServerConnection.queryNames(objAll,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some jmx-rest bridges available, that internally talk JMX to MBeans and expose the result over REST calls (which can deliver JSON as data format).

See e.g. [polarrose](http://code.google.com/p/polarrose-jmx-rest-bridge/) or [jmx-rest-access](https://github.com/thoraage/jmx-rest-access). There are a few others out there.